# Use Javascript to read all png files in a directory and display them on an HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, file, io

I have a directory full of png files and csv files. I want to some how loop through that directory and display all the png files onto a HTML page. Keep in mind that these png files don't have similar names so I have to find them by file extension.

Comment: What you did so far? What is your issue?

Comment: You cannot use client-side JavaScript to browse a folder on the server (unless the folder is configured server-side to send the directory index). What people usually do is use server-side code (for instance PHP) to read the folder and generate HTML or JSON accordingly.

Comment: Requesting this files with PHP

Answer (score 0):

First thing I should say is Java Script code is executed Client Side.

So it cannot access the server side files except in some rare cases.

But there are some Server side Languages like ASP.NET and PHP to execute the code server side.

To display the index of the particular folder `/folder/` make the folder public and delete the index.html or default.asp files from it and the open the url in any browser. It will show the index of the folder. `/folder/`

Open this official PHP link for more information about displaying list of files.
[PHP: scandir - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php)